# Android jumpy keyboard on Done keyboard key click

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm seeing a glitch with the TextField in jetpack compose with a Done ime action. When I tap Done, the keyboard dismisses completely for 1 frame, then resumes showing and dismisses with proper animation. This is very noticeable when I have elements that are positioned based on the keyboard's height. Tested on SDK 32, 33, 34 and all have the issue.

I tried to add custom action to manually dismiss the keyboard on Done using `LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current.hide()`, this seems to reduce the chance of the glitch showing.

Is this an Android bug? Is there a workaround to completely eliminate the glitch?

I tested on a very simple TextField: `TextField(value = TextFieldValue(), onValueChange = {}, keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done))`

Slightly slowed down screen capture:
[image]

Comment: Are you listening for the done key being clicked?  If so, post the code of the callback function

Comment: The glitch means that a recomposition is happening. The TextField code as you have it here does not recompose. I'd assume it's another part of the Composable that's causing it

Comment: This issue is fixed in Jetpack Compose BOM 2023.08.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a workaround until Google fixes the issue. This workaround dismisses the keyboard using android classic View method when the Done button is clicked:

```
@Composable
fun Composable() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    TextField(
        ...
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = { context.hideKeyboard() }
        ),
        ...
    )
}

fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? {
    var currentContext = this
    while (currentContext is ContextWrapper) {
        if (currentContext is Activity) return currentContext
        currentContext = currentContext.baseContext
    }
    return null
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard() {
    findActivity()?.let { activity ->
        val view = activity.currentFocus ?: View(activity)
        val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcoXx.gif)

I got exactly the same problem, maybe you could send us your build.graddle so that we can compare the versions we use to see what we have in common

(I'm using compose-bom = "2023.08.00")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).